EF Core Relationship many tables with one with non using FK
I started studying the Entity Framework, trying to understand things that are simple for many people.
I have multiple entities in different tables, but all of these entities have a non-foreign key relationship to the same table containing a list of images.  Roughly speaking, using the Owner field, I want to get a list of images URL's.  How to correctly set up relationships using the Fluent API to access a list of images using Include() . Is this possible and am I making any mistakes when designing?
What are the best practices to achieve this task?
 public class ImageUrl
 {
     public Guid Owner { get; set; }
     public string Url { get; set; }
     public int? SortIndex { get; set; }
 }

public class EntityOne
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<ImageUrl> ImagesUrls { get; set; }
}

public class EntityTwo
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } 
    public ICollection<ImageUrl> ImagesUrls { get; set; }
}

In SQL this is simple command
SELECT Url, SortIndex
FROM ImageUrl
WHERE Owner = @id

I'm trying to establish a relationship, but I don't really understand if it's even possible
e.HasMany(p => p.ImagesUrls)     
    .WithOne()     
    .HasPrincipalKey("Owner");


IMHO you should create a TPH. eg ImageUrl<T> : ImageUrl, then each ImageUrl<T> can have a real foreign key and navigation property. Though you would need to add a discriminator to the table.

Note a TPH can model either a "polymorphic join", or "exclusive belongs to" described in https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/modeling-polymorphic-associations-in-a-relational-database

Note that for polymorphic association such as with TPH you would have a discriminator such as "OwnerType" rather than relying on the assumption that the uniqueness of a GUID across tables. There are no cross-table constraints. I never recommend poly-assoc. since you gain nothing over dedicated tables (if values are not shared) or many-to-many associations (if values are shared, which is impossible /w poly-assoc.) Aside from referential integrity issues you incur a performance penalty by forcing all tables to search across the combined set of all ImageURLs.

As far as I understand your question, from what I see, I'd add few elements, such as:

Define the navigation properties as virtual for Lazy Loading & Change Tracking, although this might slightly affect the performance, due to the overhead in proxy creation and lazy loading, it's negligible compared to the convenience of it.
It's not necessary to use a combination of Annotations and a definition using FluentApi, you could use just FluentApi all the way, including keys, and vice versa, you could also use Annotations all the way, but personally - I like FluentApi.
To avoid problems with polymorphic relationships, would be better to have two separate properties that would refer to their own tables

Respecting all of the points above, ImageUrl class would look like:
public class ImageUrl
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; } = null!;
    public int? SortIndex { get; set; }

    public Guid? EntityOneId { get; set; }
    public virtual EntityOne? EntityOne { get; set; }

    public Guid? EntityTwoId { get; set; }
    public virtual EntityTwo? EntityTwo { get; set; }
}

EntityOne:
public class EntityOne
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ImageUrl> ImageUrls { get; set; } = [];
}

EntityTwo:
public class EntityTwo
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    
    public virtual ICollection<ImageUrl> ImageUrls { get; set; } = [];
}

And then your DbContext would probably look like:
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public YourDbContext(DbContextOptions<YourDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<EntityOne> EntitiesOne => Set<EntityOne>();
    public DbSet<EntityTwo> EntitiesTwo => Set<EntityTwo>();
    public DbSet<ImageUrl> ImageUrls => Set<ImageUrl>();

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<ImageUrl>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(imageUrl => imageUrl.Id);

            entity.HasOne(imageUrl => imageUrl.EntityOne)
                  .WithMany(entityOne => entityOne.ImageUrls)
                  .HasForeignKey(imageUrl => imageUrl.EntityOneId)
                  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                  .IsRequired(false);

            entity.HasOne(imageUrl => imageUrl.EntityTwo)
                  .WithMany(entityTwo => entityTwo.ImageUrls)
                  .HasForeignKey(imageUrl => imageUrl.EntityTwoId)
                  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
                  .IsRequired(false);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityOne>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(entityOne => entityOne.Id);

            entity.HasMany(entityOne => entityOne.ImageUrls)
                  .WithOne(imageUrl => imageUrl.EntityOne)
                  .HasForeignKey(imageUrl => imageUrl.EntityOneId)
                  .IsRequired(false);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<EntityTwo>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(entityTwo => entityTwo.Id);

            entity.HasMany(entityTwo => entityTwo.ImageUrls)
                  .WithOne(imageUrl => imageUrl.EntityTwo)
                  .HasForeignKey(imageUrl => imageUrl.EntityTwoId)
                  .IsRequired(false);
        });
    }
}

In provided example, I define the navigation properties from both sides (From EntitiesOne to ImageUrl and vice versa, and the same for EntitiesTwo), but it's not necessary, as EF Core understands the definition from only one side as well, but sometimes it's good for readability, as well as doing so would ensure that relationships are correctly configured and navigation properties are properly set up.
If you're using an older version of C#, it's possible you might need to replace few things, as initializing a list with new List<ImageUrl>() instead of [], and remove = null!; with Url, as it's been introduced only in new versions of C# that nullable strings should be defined explicitly as nullable.

OwnerId can't refer to two tables. These polymorphic associations questions pop up all the time. In the end, the best solution is always to just repeat the table in question (here ImageUrl) for multiple owners.

@GertArnold adjusted my answer accordingly, thanks!

I guess, if the Id is not used as the key of the table (from what I understand), it makes sense to have individual property for each table

To set up relationships in Entity Framework (EF) using the Fluent API, you need to understand that EF Core requires foreign key properties to establish relationships. However, since you have multiple entities referencing the same table using a non-foreign key field (Owner), you can achieve the desired result by configuring a one-to-many relationship where the ImageUrl table references the Owner as the foreign key.
Here’s how you can set this up:
Modify the ImageUrl class to include a navigation property for each entity type:
 public class ImageUrl
 {
 public Guid Owner { get; set; }
 public string Url { get; set; }
 public int? SortIndex { get; set; }

 public Guid? EntityOneId { get; set; }
 public EntityOne EntityOne { get; set; }

 public Guid? EntityTwoId { get; set; }
 public EntityTwo EntityTwo { get; set; }
 }

Update EntityOne and EntityTwo classes to include navigation properties:
public class EntityOne
{
[Key]
public Guid Id { get; set; } 
public ICollection<ImageUrl> ImagesUrls { get; set; } = new List<ImageUrl> 
 ();
}

 public class EntityTwo
 {
 [Key]
 public Guid Id { get; set; } 
 public ICollection<ImageUrl> ImagesUrls { get; set; } = new List<ImageUrl>();
  }

Configure the relationships using the Fluent API in your DbContext:
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
public DbSet<EntityOne> EntitiesOne { get; set; }
public DbSet<EntityTwo> EntitiesTwo { get; set; }
public DbSet<ImageUrl> ImageUrls { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ImageUrl>()
        .HasOne(i => i.EntityOne)
        .WithMany(e => e.ImagesUrls)
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.EntityOneId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ImageUrl>()
        .HasOne(i => i.EntityTwo)
        .WithMany(e => e.ImagesUrls)
        .HasForeignKey(i => i.EntityTwoId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
   }

Querying the Data
To get a list of image URLs for a specific entity, you can use the Include method
 var entityOneWithImages = await context.EntitiesOne
.Include(e => e.ImagesUrls)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == entityOneId);

 // For EntityTwo
 var entityTwoWithImages = await context.EntitiesTwo
.Include(e => e.ImagesUrls)
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == entityTwoId);


 public class ImageUrl
 {
     public Guid Owner { get; set; }
     public string Url { get; set; }
     public int? SortIndex { get; set; }
     public EntityOne One {get; set;}

 }
builder
      .HasOne(p => p.One )
      .WithMany(ps => ps.ImagesUrls)
      .HasForeignKey(ps => ps.Owner);


Please explain how this answers the question (well, it doesn't).
